# Modifying row value based on preceding row value in pandas/python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have a set of very large dataframes and I would like to modify based on preceding row values and index following some logic.

If value is in the to be removed list of values and the preceding row has a value that is not in the to be removed list of values and the the two rows have the same index then assign the preceding value to the current value. Basically I can write it as a for loop and get the desired output in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [1,2,3,4,2,4,4,1,2]},index=['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C'])
print(df)

rem_val = [2,3]

for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df['values'].iloc[i] in rem_val and df['values'].iloc[i-1] not in rem_val and df.index[i-1]==df.index[i]:
        df['values'].iloc[i]=df['values'].iloc[i-1]

print('After removal')

print(df)
```

with output being

```
   values
A       1
A       2
A       3
A       4
B       2
B       4
B       4
C       1
C       2
After removal
   values
A       1
A       1
A       1
A       4
B       2
B       4
B       4
C       1
C       1
```

Note, for example, that the first row of B is 2 (in the to be removed list) but stayed because there is no row with B that precedes it.

Unfortunately this is a relatively slow code (there are billions of rows) but I am not sure how to vectorize/make it faster. One of the problems is that it might be that there are many (10s) of bad rows in a row that need to be adjusted so you can't compare [:-1] with [1:] for example. Is there a way to vectorize/speed up the above for loop?

Thanks,

Ilya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand clearly , using `groupby` + `mask`+`isin`

```
df.mask(df['values'].isin(rem_val)).groupby(level=0).ffill().combine_first(df)
Out[1572]: 
   values
A     1.0
A     1.0
A     1.0
A     4.0
B     2.0
B     4.0
B     4.0
C     1.0
C     1.0
```

Comment: I think you might have the solution although I honestly don't know some  of these methods so will have to check first. Thank you!

Comment: @Ilya  combine_first can be treat as fillena

Comment: Ok, so I played with this code a bit. It seems that making 'value' column into sets and then using sets in the for-loop is significantly faster than the one-liner you suggested (as in x100). Unfortunately your method relies on serializing the data and sets are unhashable.

Comment: @Ilya interesting , for loop are faster than vectorize method, if you can can you show us the timing ?